# Error in ASP.NET In web configuration file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

I am a java developer so don't know anything about ASP.NET. Please explain in a layman's terms.

> Configuration Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 30:         `<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>`
>   Line 31:         `<add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>`
>   Line 32:         `<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>`
>   Line 33:         `<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>`
>   Line 34:         `<add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>`

Comment: What part of "The system cannot find the file specified." did you not understand?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am not able to find that file. if you can send me the link of the file that would be great

Comment: Yeah, and neither is .NET able to find that file! It's not there!

Answer (score 3):

You can install the Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package and change your references so they point to the ones installed by the package.

[Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=6442)

---

Search the missing dll in your system

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll
```

You find them in "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL" and put them in the references of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the **missing assembly (DLL) references** into your project "References" section and then perform the build again to check if is corrected.